Extract swagger definition from azure logic app standard workflow
Does anyone know of a way to extract a swagger (open api) definition from a logic app standard workflow that has a htpp trigger please?

not sure if there is an equivalent for logic app standard but probably: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/list-swagger?view=rest-logic-2016-06-01&tabs=HTTP

Hi @Thomas, thanks for the answer. I did see that api for logic app consumption but unfortunately it seems that there is no equivalent for standard yet - at least not one I've been able to find
